# java, treque, instantiating an array with class t

Tags: java

I have a class which has the constructor

```
public Treque(Class<T> t) {

}
```

I need to instantiate an array which has the class t. How do I instantiate it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int-

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your exact goal is. If you want something arbitrary, go with reflection. If you simply want to pass an object that inherits a class, you can do that with different syntax.

Since your example is using Class, try these reflection examples:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html
- [Is there a way to instantiate a class by name in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886266/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-a-class-by-name-in-java)

I think the accepted answer here is what you are looking for. [Java Generics Creating Array from Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069301/java-generics-creating-array-from-class)

And a little bit more:

```
    public void test(Class<T> t) {
            T[] a=new T[10];//complie error

        Object array = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(t, 10);//lots of ambiguity
        String[] arrT = (String[]) array;//works if you know the final type

        Object[] anyType = new Object[10];
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
               anyType[i] = createObject(t.getName());
        //You will need to cast the Object to your desired type
        }
      static Object createObject(String className) {
          //http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/ObjectReflectioncreatenewinstance.htm
      Object object = null;
      try {
          Class classDefinition = Class.forName(className);
          object = classDefinition.newInstance();
      } catch (InstantiationException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
      }
      return object;
   }
```